# Footnote in table

Tags: tables, footnotes

I have some table like the following one and want to write some configuration using ´footnote´.

```
\begin{table}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{footnotesize}
     \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
     \hline 
     TPA & Components & Cost \\ \hline
      & Total & 56558.4 \\ \hline 
     \end{tabular}
    \end{footnotesize}
    \caption[]{Hardware cost estimation~\footnote{per router}}
    \label{tab:}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
```

So, I did a method like https://texfaq.org/FAQ-ftncapt.
However, I found upper subscript but didn't figure out how to use a footnote in my table.
Where is the footnote I wrote? I want to see "per router".

Could you please fix my LaTeX code?

Comment: Why not simply saying "Hardware cost estimation (per router)"?

Comment: I'm going to be a hypocrite and put [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) here.

Answer (score 42):

You might want to use the [`tablefootnote`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tablefootnote) package (and probably you want to

1. remove the `\begin{footnotesize} \end{footnotesize}`, otherwise the table is printed in footnote size;
2. replace the `center`-environment by a simple `\centering`; and
3. remove the `~` before the `\tablefootnote`, because the `~` causes a (non-breakable) space before the footnote-mark).

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  %\begin{center}% replaced by \centering
  \centering
    %\begin{footnotesize}
     \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
     \hline 
     TPA & Components & Cost \\ \hline
      & Total & 56558.4 \\ \hline 
     \end{tabular}
    %\end{footnotesize}
    \caption[Hardware cost estimation]{%
      Hardware cost estimation\tablefootnote{per router}\label{tab:}}
  %\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems that `\cite` cannot be used within tablefootnote.

Answer (score 22):

You didn't follow the instructions. The footnote appears when you use a `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}                                                                                         
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline 
TPA & Components & Cost \\
\hline
 & Total & 56558.4 \\                                                                                             
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\caption[Hardware cost estimation]{Hardware cost estimation~\footnote{per router}}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: result]

The `footnotesize` environment is not necessary. The label is not mandatory, when you don't need a `label` you don't need to use it.

As the link you posted already explains: Use the optional argument of `caption` to provide a version without footnote for the TOC.

Comment: However, this show a, not indexing number.

Comment: I think that that does not works properly

Comment: @JHL: Please always provide some info other than "it does not work properly".  Per you other comment, to get `minipage` footnotes to use numbers use `\renewcommand\thempfootnote{\arabic{mpfootnote}}`.

Answer (score 8):

Might be better to

- place the caption above the table
- use table notes, to place comments under the table. Note: table notes are not the same as footnotes. Footnotes and floating objects does not mix well.

Comment: May be worth an example in here.