# Footnotes being rendered as letters inside tabular

Tags: tables, numbering, footnotes

I wrote a couple of footnotes inside a table using `minipage`, but they are rendered as letters instead of numbers. I couldn't find anything about it in Google. I tried using

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
```

inside the `minipage`, but it didn't help. What can I do?

Comment: could you provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) for folks to play with?

Comment: What about a fbox or mbox? Isn't the same thing but...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The footnote counter inside a minipage is `mpfootnote` rather than `footnote`, and by default, such footnotes are formatted as `\alph`.  If you simply want the footnotes to be numbered (and have a numbering independent of your main footnote numbering) then it suffices to use

```
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}
```

There are other ways to put footnotes in tables, in particular the `threeparttable` package or the `tablefootnote` package.  See, for example:

- [Footnote in table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35615/2693)
- [Add notes under the table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12676/2693)

Comment: Thank you, that did it. I chose `minipage` because it seemed simpler than the other alternatives.

Answer (score 5):

Within `minipages`, the counter for footnotes is independent of the footnote counter outside of a `minipage`.  Issue the following within your `minipage` and things should work as you wish:

```
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}
```