# Multisection bibliography item

Tags: sectioning, bibliographies

I have a bibliography in my `book` article as follow :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    bookmarks=true,
    colorlinks=true,
    pdftitle={Title},
    pdfauthor={Author},
    pdfsubject={Subject},
    pdfkeywords={Keywords},
    linktoc=toc,
    linktocpage=true,
    pdfdisplaydoctitle=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue,
    pdffitwindow=true,
    pdfstartview=FitH
}
\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\bibname{Ouvrages généraux}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem[og1]{doc1} Indian \TeX\  Users Group, {\it \LaTeX\ Tutorials -- A Primer}, \url{https://www.tug.org/twg/mactex/tutorials/ltxprimer-1.0.pdf}, Trivandrum, India, 2003 September.
\end{thebibliography}
\renewcommand\bibname{Ouvrages spéciaux}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem[os1]{book1} Laurent AUDIBERT, {\it UML 2}, Editions 2007-2008, Institut Universitaire de Technologie de Villetaneuse – Département Informatique, \url{http://www-lipn.univ-paris13.fr/audibert/pages/enseignement/cours.htm}
    \bibitem[os2]{book2} Pascal Roques, {\it UM2 - Modéliser une application web}, 4$^\text{e}$ édition, Eyrolles.

    \setcounter{firstbib}{\value{enumiv}}
\end{thebibliography}

\renewcommand\bibname{Mémoires}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    %\bibliographystyle{alpha}
    \bibitem[mem1]{mem1} Komlatsè N. NOUKAFOU, Mémoire de fin de cycle Ingénieur 2012-2013.

\end{thebibliography}

\renewcommand\bibname{Références web}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem[web1]{website:wikipedia-MVC} Wikipedia.org, {\it Architecture MVC},  \url{http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mod\%C3\%A8le-vue-contr\%C3\%B4leur}, consulté ce 13 août 2014.

    \bibitem[web2]{website:devlop} Developpez.com, {\it Quel SGBD choisir ?}  \url{http://fadace.developpez.com/sgbdcmp}, consulté ce 15 août 2014.

    \bibitem[web3]{website:nico} Le blog de Nicholat Hachet, {\it Pourquoi utiliser un framework PHP ?} \url{http://blog.nicolashachet.com/technologies/php/pourquoi-utiliser-un-framework-php/}, consulté ce 12 novembre 2014.

    \bibitem[web4]{website:devweb} Graphisme \& Développement web, {\it Utiliser un framework PHP, est-ce toujours un bon choix ?}, \url{http://blog.webodrey.fr/post/utiliser-un-framework-php-est-ce-toujours-un-bon-choix}, consulté ce 31 octobre 2014.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

But referencing items of the `Référence web` section references the first page of the document, although the `thebibliography` environnement is on the last page.
Is there something wrong ? Anyone to fill me a solution ?

**Edit1**
I have completed the code. 
When adding a footnote today, I remark that the link refers to the first page of the document. How to fix this ?

**Edit 2** 
Correction of an error in the code.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can now fix my problem. I just need to remove `website:` from my `\bibitem` parameter in `Référence web` section.
Something like :

```
\bibitem[web1]{wikipedia-MVC} Wikipedia.org, {\it Architecture MVC},  \url{http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mod\%C3\%A8le-vue-contr\%C3\%B4leur}, consulté ce 13 août 2014.
```

And I can refer simply to it,

```
\cite{wikipedia-MVC}
```

and see link to the appropriate page. Thanks to all for the help.

Comment: With the posted code that change does not make a difference to the links.

Comment: @andrewswann the posted code (at the top of the question) doesn't even compile, because of extra brace in `\documentclass{[11pt,a4paper]{book}`; should we assume that everyone will _know_ to correct things like that?

Comment: @wasteofspace, it's an error when I was typing the code here, I'll correct it. Now the problem is solved as I mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: @wasteofspace I made several corrections to the code in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `\label`s to your `bibliography`s that you can refer to.  Putting `\label{bib:mem}` in this position

```
\renewcommand\bibname{Mémoires}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}\label{bib:mem}
```

will enable you to reference that point via

```
\hyperref[bib:web]{Références web}
```

Here is the code in your complete document with missing packages added:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    bookmarks=true,
    colorlinks=true,
    pdftitle={Title},
    pdfauthor={Author},
    pdfsubject={Subject},
    pdfkeywords={Keywords},
    linktoc=toc,
    linktocpage=true,
    pdfdisplaydoctitle=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue,
    pdffitwindow=true,
    pdfstartview=FitH
}
\urlstyle{same}
\newcounter{firstbib}

\begin{document}

\hyperref[bib:web]{Références web}

\renewcommand\bibname{Ouvrages généraux}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}\label{bib:og}
    \bibitem[og1]{doc1} Indian \TeX\  Users Group, {\it \LaTeX\
      Tutorials -- A Primer},
      \url{https://www.tug.org/twg/mactex/tutorials/ltxprimer-1.0.pdf},
      Trivandrum, India, 2003 September. 
\end{thebibliography}

\renewcommand\bibname{Ouvrages spéciaux}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}\label{bib:os}
    \bibitem[os1]{book1} Laurent AUDIBERT, {\it UML 2}, Editions
      2007-2008, Institut Universitaire de Technologie de Villetaneuse
      – Département Informatique,
      \url{http://www-lipn.univ-paris13.fr/audibert/pages/enseignement/cours.htm} 
    \bibitem[os2]{book2} Pascal Roques, {\it UM2 - Modéliser une
      application web}, 4$^\text{e}$ édition, Eyrolles. 

    \setcounter{firstbib}{\value{enumiv}}
\end{thebibliography}

\renewcommand\bibname{Mémoires}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}\label{bib:mem}
    %\bibliographystyle{alpha}
    \bibitem[mem1]{mem1} Komlatsè N. NOUKAFOU, Mémoire de fin de cycle Ingénieur 2012-2013.

\end{thebibliography}

\renewcommand\bibname{Références web}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}\label{bib:web}
\bibitem[web1]{website:wikipedia-MVC} Wikipedia.org, {\it Architecture
  MVC},
  \url{http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mod\%C3\%A8le-vue-contr\%C3\%B4leur},
  consulté ce 13 août 2014.

\bibitem[web2]{website:devlop} Developpez.com, {\it Quel SGBD choisir
  ?}  \url{http://fadace.developpez.com/sgbdcmp}, consulté ce 15 août
  2014.

\bibitem[web3]{website:nico} Le blog de Nicholat Hachet, {\it Pourquoi
  utiliser un framework PHP ?}
  \url{http://blog.nicolashachet.com/technologies/php/pourquoi-utiliser-un-framework-php/},
  consulté ce 12 novembre 2014.

\bibitem[web4]{website:devweb} Graphisme \& Développement web, {\it
  Utiliser un framework PHP, est-ce toujours un bon choix ?},
  \url{http://blog.webodrey.fr/post/utiliser-un-framework-php-est-ce-toujours-un-bon-choix},
  consulté ce 31 octobre 2014.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can see. The problem is that certain links work correctly, but some others not. Specially, items of `Référence web` section link to the first page of my document. Recently, adding a footnote is producing a linked number refering to the first page too. Any text at the bottom of the page as it might be.

Comment: You need to post more code to show us how you are citing and how you are making footnotes.  A direct `\cite{website:nico}` works correctly for me.

Comment: The problem with the footnote is that it is in a `tabular` environment; how can add a footnote in such an environment ? For the `Références web` section items, I have not already fixed it.

Comment: Footnotes don't work directly in tables.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35615/15925 for solutions.