# Footnotes in table with savenotes

Tags: tables, footnotes

After considering options for getting my footnotes to work ([Footnotes in tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1583/footnotes-in-tables)), I settled on the savenotes environment.

Sadly it seems to work randomly, based on the position in the table.
I have three footnotes and only the third works correctly, for the others I get the warning "name{Hfootnote.1} has been referenced but does not exist". When I insert the footnote#3 next to footnote#2 I get a warning for that as well.

Here is the full table, please tell me how to fix it:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[hang, flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}

\begin{document}

\begin{savenotes}
\begin{table}
\begin{quote}
\caption{Kurzer Vergleich von Unit-Test und Integrationstest}
\label{tab:testcomparison}
\centering\small
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm} p{7cm}}
\emph{Unit-Test} &
\emph{Integrationstest} 
\\
\hline
Resultate hängen nur von Java Code ab& Resultate hängen auch von externen Systemen ab \\
Einfach zu schreiben und zu überprüfen&Setup des Integrationstests kann kompliziert sein\\
Eine einzelne Klasse/Einheit wird isoliert getestet&Eine oder mehrere Komponenten werden getestet\\
Alle Abhängigkeiten werden falls nötig gemocked&Es werden keine Mocks\footnote{Mocks sind Test-Doubles.} benutzt (oder nur Komponenten die in keinem Zusammenhang stehen werden gemocked)\\
Test überprüft nur die Implementierung des Codes&Test überprüft die Implementierung individueller Komponenten und deren Kopplungsverhalten bei gemeinsamer Nutzung\\
Ein Unit-Test benutzt nur JUnit/TestNG und ein Mocking-Framework&Ein Integrationstest kann wirkliche Container\footnote{Ein Container ist eine Software-Komponente eines Application Servers, die Objekte der gehosteten Applikation verwaltet.}, wirkliche Datenbanken und spezielle Integrationstest-Frameworks(z.B. Arquillian oder DbUnit) benutzen\\
Meistens von Entwicklern benutzt&Integrationstests sind auch nützlich für Qualitätsmanagement, DevOps\footnote{DevOps ist ein Softwareentwicklungsprozess der IT, Entwicklung und Qualitätsmanagement zusammenbringt.}, Help Desk\\
Ein fehlgeschlagener Unit-Test ist immer eine Regression (wenn die Anforderungen sich nicht geändert haben)&Ein fehlgeschlagener Integrationstest kann auch bedeuten, dass der Code noch korrekt ist, aber sich die Umgebung geändert hat\\
Unit-Tests sollten in einer Enterprise-Applikation ungefähr 5 Minuten dauern&Integrationstest können in einer Enterprise-Applikation Stunden dauern\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{quote}
\end{table}
\end{savenotes}

\end{document}
```

Hope you don't mind the German and thanks for your time.

EDIT: Replaced Code with full document. After compiling you will notice, that only the third footnote marker jumps to the note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35669/97184

After looking at all the different workarounds and not getting savenotes to work, tablefootnote-package seems to be the only solution that is simple and works.

Too bad I get the footnote on the previous page, but I'll try fixing that too.
Other answers still welcome!